# Pure tailwind CSS solution for image scale effect

Tags: tailwind-css

[image: Card screenshot]

I want to create the above UI. It has the following properties.

1. There is a title at the bottom of the image, which is stacked on top of the image.
2. Image should zoom-in when mouse hover on the image.
3. Also, the image should zoom-in when mouse hover on the title.

I can do that perfectly fine, with the following code.

**component.tsx**

```html
<div className="card relative h-full w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md">
  <div
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.slug})` }}
    className="image relative w-full h-full bg-cover bg-center transition-transform duration-700 ease-out"
  />
  <div className="absolute bottom-0 w-full text-center text-white">
    <Link href={post.slug} className="block p-2">
      {post.title}
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

**global.css**

```css
.card:hover .image {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

While this working perfectly fine, I just need to know whether there is a solution for this that doesn't use any custom `css`. That uses only pure tailwind css.

After some searching, I found [this article about custom variants](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#arbitrary-values-but-for-variants:%7E:text=You%20can%20even%20style%20the%20first%20p%20inside%20the%20div%20in%20the%20second%20child%20li%20but%20only%20on%20hover%3A). It only zooms the image when mouse-hover on the image, but not on the title. I can't just add `pointer-events-none` class because I want the title to be clickable.

```html
<div className="relative h-full w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md hover:[&>div:first-child]:scale-110">
  <div
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${post.slug})` }}
    className="relative w-full h-full bg-cover bg-center transition-transform duration-700 ease-out"
  />
  <div className="absolute bottom-0 w-full text-center text-white">
    <Link href={post.slug} className="block p-2">
      {post.title}
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Does tailwind translate `<div />` in your markup to valid HTML `<div></div>`? Cause there is no such thing.

Comment: This is NextJS. So, it handled by the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [`group-hover` variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-screen w-screen">
  <div class="relative h-full w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md group">
    <div
      style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/300"
      class="relative w-full h-full bg-cover bg-center transition-transform duration-700 ease-out group-hover:scale-110"
    >
    </div>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 w-full text-center text-white">
      <a href="#" class="block p-2">
        {post.title}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```